# Importing python libraries in Julia

Tags: python, import, julia, libraries

As a python user I find Julia very easy to learn as a lot of syntax is the same. Only with some extra sugar syntax and a lot of math related advantages. Also it seems so much faster every time I solve a problem in Julia and python at the same time. I am now thinking what language to focus on, naturally that would be Julia for me now as I don't see any disadvantages. Also, all python libraries can be easily imported in Julia. That raises me the question, is there any disadvantage of importing python libraries in Julia, instead of using the python libraries in python?

Comment: The main drawback I experienced is that it adds another layer to your software stack which may not be perfectly transparent and so every once in a while you will run into an interoperability issues which may require quite a bit of googling / stackoverflowing to fix.

Comment: Also, open-ended questions like yours may have more traction on https://discourse.julialang.org/ than on StackOverflow

Comment: I agree that such question should be posted to discourse, but generally, not everything works well when you use python libraries in julia and there are some bugs and problems (e.g. you can't pickle julia objects using python pickle module, see issue https://github.com/JuliaPy/PyCall.jl/issues/863 ).
Also, python has much wider ecosystem and more libraries, which is advantage in some usecases.

Comment: Sometimes, when you add another layer there are hard-to-find bugs, e.g. in my team we use PyCall from julia and sometimes, the call hangs indefinitely, and we don't know why. We hope we will solve that quickly and I know it's very anecdotal example, but such things sometimes happen.